# Stop module loading

Tags: python, module

I'd like to stop the loading of a module if some modules dependencies arent on machine, how can i do that?

```
try:
    import lxml
except:
    print "This module requires lxml"
    # WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE TO STOP MODULE LOADING?

class foo:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raise the exception, or raise a new one:

```
try:
    import lxml
except:
    raise SomeError('This module requires lxml')
```

If you want to stop the interpreter entirely, use `exit()` to terminate the program.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the whole python interpreter you can use [sys.exit()](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html)